# Using the content handler API (JSR 211) to open applications

Tags: java, java-me, mobile-phones

I want to be able to launch native and J2ME applications through my application using the content handler API (JSR 211) on a Nokia 6212.

At the moment, I am unable to do so, as it always states that there is "No Content Handler Found" and throws a `javax.microedition.content.ContentHandlerException`.

At the moment, I am trying to get the phone to launch its browser and go to a certain website, just to test that I can use the framework. I have tried many different `Invocation` objects:

```
//throw exceptions
new Invocation("http://www.somesite.com/index.html",
  "application/internet-shortcut");
new Invocation("http://www.google.co.uk","text/html");
// a long shot, I know
new Invocation("http://www.somesite.com/text.txt","text/plain");
// massive long shot
new Invocation("http://www.google.co.uk","application/browser");

//appears to download the link and content (and definitely does in the Nokia
// emulator) and then throws an exception
new Invocation("http://www.google.co.uk");
new Invocation("http://www.somesite.com/index.html");
```

Below is the code that I have been using, please bear in mind the parameters often changed to generate the different `Invocation` objects.

```
/*
 * Invokes an application using the Content Handler API
 */
public void doInvoke(String url, String mime, String payload){
    Registry register = Registry.getRegistry(this.getClass().getName());
    Invocation invoke = new Invocation(url, mime, null, false,
      ContentHandler.ACTION_OPEN);

    boolean mustQuit = false;

    try {
        mustQuit = register.invoke(invoke);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ContentHandlerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(mustQuit){
        this.quit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Registry register = Registry.getRegistry(this.getClass().getName());
```

You must call `Registry.getRegistry` for the MIDlet inheritor. Just use your MIDlet for getting the class name.